# Daisy chain shared folder in Windows?

Tags: windows

Is it possible to daisy chain a shared folder in Windows? As in:

Machine A only has permission to talk to B, and A is sharing a folder to B. C wants a file in A's shared directory. Can B re-share the directory from A and serve it to C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen or heard of this so at first blush I'd have to say that it isn't possible. B can't share a non-local resource, nor can it "reshare" a share on A that it's connected to.

Answer (score 5):

I didn't try this myself (yet) but that's what I found elsewhere when researching the exact same question:

```
> MKLINK /D C:\WDTV \\W2008R2\Media
> NET Share Media=C:\WDTV
```

Source: http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/78598-re-sharing-mapped-shared-drive.html

Comment: Beware that it still is a symbolic link also from the view of C. So C needs to be able to reach A. Also there are restrictions regarding those ponting to remote servers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229643/how-do-i-overcome-the-the-symbolic-link-cannot-be-followed-because-its-type-is

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  There is no way to "re-share" a share in Windows.  In Linux + SAMBA, there are hundreds of ways of accomplishing this.  The only way to give the illusion of something similar, is to make use of DFS Links and a common namespace.  In 99% of cases, this is WAAAAY more work to setup and maintain than simply directly mapping to a specific server.