# Access CIFS share through another server

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cifs

I have CIFS-share on NAS-server and that share is accessible to one server.

That share is mounted to my server

\NAS-server\share -> U:\

The server to which the NAS-share is mounted is sharing its local disks to another servers.

I was wondering whether its possible to share that CIFS-share to another machines which currently use the local disks on the same server. As is the server is acting like a proxy for that actual NAS-server?

Comment: No.  http://serverfault.com/questions/444438/daisy-chain-shared-folder-in-windows